# Orkut style div update on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update a div on click similar to orkut .. The div is updating fine. But when the user clicks on the textbox its value becomes null initially. So the user has to again type the whole thing. So what I need is a facililty for the user to add the text with the existing one. So when he clicks on the textbox, the existing value of textbox would remain there and allows user to append new text. Please find the code below for that..

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.photo_title').click(

    function(e){

        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).val('');

        $('<input type="text" value="sdfsdfsdfsdf"    />').appendTo($(this)).val(text).select().blur(
            function(){
                var newText = $(this).val();
                    if(newText==""){newText="enter text "}

                $(this).parent().text(newText),find("form input:text" ).remove();

        });
    }); 
});
```

## HTML

```
<div class="photo_title">My text goes here and type here to add more</div>
```

Comment: Take care with code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place something like the following at the top of your click handler

```
if (e.target != this) return;
```

Otherwise, the handler will be triggered when the user clicks in the text box as well since the event will bubble up. So your code will end up looking like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.photo_title').click(
        function(e){
            if (e.target != this) return;
            ...
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: You should also change $(this).val(''); to $(this).html('');

Comment: Thanks dude.. It worked..I placed it after  var text = $(this).text(); and works fine.. Still I am not sure why should we use that.. I am a complete beginner in JS..:)

Comment: After the user clicks once, the input box gets inserted into the div. If the user clicks on the input box, that click event first gets handled by any click handlers attached to the input box. Then, the event works its way up the DOM tree and gets handled by any other click handlers along the way. Since the photo_title div is a parent of the input box, its click handler is called again, and since it now contains no text, it sets the value of the input to an empty string.